# Download file in mobile device

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have done with download in pc device with below code

```
    $file_url_source = "C:/test.xlsx";
    $file_url = "C:/test.xlsx";
    header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=UTF-8;');  
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file_url_source)."") . '"';
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_url));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file_url);
```

But it's not working for mobile device (I just tested it in Android mobile and it downloads the `download.php` file). How can I make mobile devices download the file?

Comment: Why are you setting content type and  disposition multiple times?

Comment: @ElefantPhace i just edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
$file_url = "xxxxxx";
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file_url) .'"');
readfile($file_url);
```

Your problem is with this line

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file_url_source)."") . '"';
#                                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^
#              this is where your problem is, you never put the last " around the file name
```